# Powershell Import-Csv Number of Results

Tags: string, powershell, csv

I want to check the value of the "Code" property of the .csv database. If the first three characters of the "Code" field is equal to (-eq) to The first three characters of the "Product", display the number of results (The count) and add the input to the .csv database.

However, the count is not being displayed as if the results were null.

```
foreach ($row in $InventoryContents) 
{
    #Lets build a String first
    $exportString = $row.User +','+$row.Product+','+$row.Company+','+$row.Model+',';
    #Everything right so far

    #first three characters of Product
    $firstKey = $row.Product.SubString(0,3).ToUpper()
    echo $firstKey;

    #problem here
    $nonSortedContents = Import-Csv $nonSortedCsv | where-Object { ($_.Code.split('-')[0]) -eq $firstKey }
    #but arrapently this works : Import-Csv $nonSortedCsv| where-Object { ($_.Code.split('-')[0]) -eq "MON"}


    $lines = $nonSortedContents.count
    echo $lines
    #null


    #if not enetered
    if ($lines -eq $null)
    {
            $wholeKey = $firstKey +'-'+  ("{0:D5}" -f 0).ToString()
            $exportString = $exportString + $wholeKey
            $exportString -join  "," >> $nonSortedCsv
    }
    else
    {
            $wholeKey = $firstKey +'-'+  ("{0:D5}" -f $lines).ToString()
            $exportString = $exportString + $wholeKey
            $exportString -join  "," >> $nonSortedCsv
    }
}
```

I got it to work with

> $nonSortedContents = 
>   @(Import-Csv $nonSortedCsv | where-Object { ($_.Code.split('-')[0]) -eq $firstKey })

Apparently when there is only one line in a CSV file Import-Csv returns a
PSCustomObject. When there are more than one line, the object returned is an
Object[].

Comment: Thanks. Hit the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a conditionally populated array:

```
$csv = if ($someCondition) {
  @(Import-CSV someFile.csv)
} else {
  @(Import-CSV someFile.csv | Where-Object { $_.someColumn -eq "someValue" })
}
```

However, just surrounding the `Import-CSV` line with the array notation `@(...)` wasn't enough. In my case, I had to also explicitly declare the variable as an array (`[array] $csv`). Eg:

```
[array] $csv = if ($someCondition) {
  @(Import-CSV someFile.csv)
} else {
  @(Import-CSV someFile.csv | Where-Object { $_.someColumn -eq "someValue" })
}
```

I got hints from here: http://poshoholic.com/2009/07/03/powershell-quick-tip-when-you-store-an-array-make-sure-it-is-an-array/ and here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/L5J3WffAu9A/vK1mKj2nVncJ

Comment: Was it "not enough" because of the surrounding `if`? That is, I believe returning from the `if` "flattened" the single-item array just like `Import-CSV` did. That means you could remove the surrounding `@()` in your `if` clauses; they're just boxing the value to be immediately unboxed as it's returned. Instead, *simply* force an array as you do, or perhaps surround the entire `if` -- `$a = @(if ($true) { Import-Csv someFile.csv } ...)` -- if you always return an array, instead.